# Getting CURL in PHP to work (replacing with variables)

Tags: php, curl

The following codes work and the email was sent out using my sendinblue API:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{  \n   \"sender\":{  \n      \"name\":\"My name\",\n      \"email\":\"admin@mydomain.sg\"\n   },\n   \"to\":[  \n      {  \n         \"email\":\"hisname@hisdomain.com\",\n         \"name\":\"His name\"\n      }\n   ],\n   \"subject\":\"Testing email on request\",\n   \"htmlContent\":\"<html><head></head><body><p>Hello,</p>This is my first transactional email sent from Sendinblue.</p></body></html>\"\n}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Api-Key: I removed API Key before posting this question';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

But I would like to replace the sender name and email with variables but it didn't work out when I replace the

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{  \n   \"sender\":{  \n      \"name\":\"My name\",\n      \"email\":\"admin@mydomain.sg\"\n   },\n   \"to\":[  \n      {  \n         \"email\":\"hisname@hisdomain.com\",\n         \"name\":\"His name\"\n      }\n   ],\n   \"subject\":\"Testing email on request\",\n   \"htmlContent\":\"<html><head></head><body><p>Hello,</p>This is my first transactional email sent from Sendinblue.</p></body></html>\"\n}");
```

with:

```
$myname = "My Name";
$myemail = "admin@mydomain.sg";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{  \n   \"sender\":{  \n      \"name\":$myname,\n      \"email\":$myemail\n   },\n   \"to\":[  \n      {  \n         \"email\":\"hisname@hisdomain.com\",\n         \"name\":\"His name\"\n      }\n   ],\n   \"subject\":\"Testing email on request\",\n   \"htmlContent\":\"<html><head></head><body><p>Hello,</p>This is my first transactional email sent from Sendinblue.</p></body></html>\"\n}");
```

Can anyone let me know where is the issue?

Sorry, I'm a beginner in coding... Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Remember to always post the message error you are facing so that it will be easier to help and understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could be facing an error because you are trying to insert a variable inside a JSON string but missed to wrap the variable with double quotes. Strings in JSON must always be wrapped in double quotes.

Dealing with JSON strings directly like this is generally not a good idea, unless it's a very short or simple string.

A better approach could be to use an array and then convert the array to a string  with `json_encode`, in case you need a JSON string.

Instead of creating an array from scratch, let's be lazy: you can use `json_decode` to convert the same string used in `curl_setopt` into an associative array.

```php
$curlPostfields = json_decode("{  \n   \"sender\":{  \n      \"name\":\"My name\",\n      \"email\":\"admin@mydomain.sg\"\n   },\n   \"to\":[  \n      {  \n         \"email\":\"hisname@hisdomain.com\",\n         \"name\":\"His name\"\n      }\n   ],\n   \"subject\":\"Testing email on request\",\n   \"htmlContent\":\"<html><head></head><body><p>Hello,</p>This is my first transactional email sent from Sendinblue.</p></body></html>\"\n}", 
                              $association = true);
```

Looking at the docs for [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you can see that the option `$association = true` creates an associative array instead of an object.

The array content is dumped below.

```php
>>> var_dump($curlPostfields);
array(4) {
  ["sender"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "My name"
    ["email"]=>
    string(17) "admin@mydomain.sg"
  }
  ["to"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(21) "hisname@hisdomain.com"
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "His name"
    }
  }
  ["subject"]=>
  string(24) "Testing email on request"
  ["htmlContent"]=>
  string(114) "<html><head></head><body><p>Hello,</p>This is my first transactional email sent from Sendinblue.</p></body></html>"
}
```

It's now easy to change as you need the sender `name` and `email` fields, you just need to edit directly the array.

```php
$myCustomName = 'Mr. Custom Name';
$myCustomMail = 'admin@customdomain.me"';

$curlPostfields['sender']['name'] = $myCustomName;
$curlPostfields['sender']['name'] = $myCustomMail;
```

Now you can just convert back the array to a JSON string, [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will handle all the double quotes and stuff.

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curlPostfields));
```